Laravel Herd file upload fails
I'm using Laravel Herd for my environment setup. Everything works fine but file uploads fail.
I get this error: The logo failed to upload.
validation code: ['logo' => ['required', 'max:255', 'file', 'image']]
controller code: $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public')

make sure DEBUG environment is true and env is local. check logs again. are you using minio?

do a $path = $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public');  and give the error
